# Warning: procedure created with compilation errors in terminal

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
    CUST_NUM    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    CUST_LNAME  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CUST_FNAME  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CUST_BALANCE    NUMBER(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00
);
```

I created this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_CUSTOMER
    (IN cust_num INTEGER,
     IN cust_lname varchar(15),
     IN cust_fname varchar(15),
     IN cust_balance number(9,2)) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUST_NUM, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME, CUST_BALANCE)
    VALUES (cust_num, cust_lname, cust_fname, cust_balance);

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: This looks like oracle code but is tagged mysql? Please publish error code.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you need to:

- remove the precision from the types in the signature;
- `IN` comes after the identifier for the argument;
- add an `IS` (or `AS`) keyword between the signature and `BEGIN`;
- (and `VARCHAR` is an alias for `VARCHAR2`).

Like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_CUSTOMER(
  p_cust_num     IN INTEGER,
  p_cust_lname   IN varchar2,
  p_cust_fname   IN varchar2,
  p_cust_balance IN number
)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUST_NUM, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME, CUST_BALANCE)
  VALUES(p_cust_num, p_cust_lname, p_cust_fname, p_cust_balance);
END;
/
```

*Note: You should not `COMMIT` in procedures as it prevents you chaining multiple procedures together and then using `ROLLBACK` on them all if a later one fails. Instead, `COMMIT` from the code you use to call the procedure.*

*Note 2: It is also good practice to name your PL/SQL variables differently to the column names so that when you use the PL/SQL variables in a query then they are not shadowed by the locally-defined SQL columns.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TM39IwdW)

Comment: @BaoDao I was in the process of updating the answer as you commented. You were also missing an `IS` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

> The error that i got is : Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors. How can I fix it?

If you used some GUI tool - such as TOAD or SQL Developer - you'd *visually*  know that something's wrong with your code. For example, this is TOAD:

[image]

Basically, it says that `IN` is misplaced (parameter name first, optionally IN/OUT (or both), datatype with no precision).

---

If you use command-line tool (such as SQL*Plus)

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_CUSTOMER(
  2  IN cust_num INTEGER,
  3  IN cust_lname varchar(15),
  4  IN cust_fname varchar(15),
  5  IN cust_balance number(9,2))
  6  BEGIN
  7  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUST_NUM, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME, CUST_BALANCE)
  8  VALUES(cust_num, cust_lname, cust_fname, cust_balance);
  9  COMMIT;
 10  END;
 11  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

you'd have to find error cause yourself. How? By querying `user_errors`:

```
SQL> select line, position, text
  2  from user_errors
  3  where name = 'PRC_ADD_CUSTOMER';

      LINE   POSITION TEXT
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         2          1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:

                         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
                         current delete exists prior


SQL>
```

---

I'm not going to debug your code error-by-error. This is code that compiles and *works*:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_add_customer (p_cust_num      IN INTEGER,
  2                                                p_cust_lname    IN VARCHAR2,
  3                                                p_cust_fname    IN VARCHAR2,
  4                                                p_cust_balance  IN NUMBER)
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7     INSERT INTO customer (cust_num,
  8                           cust_lname,
  9                           cust_fname,
 10                           cust_balance)
 11          VALUES (p_cust_num,
 12                  p_cust_lname,
 13                  p_cust_fname,
 14                  p_cust_balance);
 15  END;
 16  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    prc_add_customer(1, 'Little', 'Foot', 100);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from customer;

  CUST_NUM CUST_LNAME      CUST_FNAME      CUST_BALANCE
---------- --------------- --------------- ------------
         1 Little          Foot                     100

SQL>
```

Note several things:

- pay attention to correct syntax. Documentation exists for reason - read it
- Oracle recommends we use `varchar2` datatype (not `varchar`)
- don't name parameters the same as column names; for example, you can use a prefix (such as `p_` in my example). For insert operations it doesn't matter, but for updates you might get unexpected result
- don't commit within a procedure; let caller decide whether to commit (or not)

Comment: huge respect for you, thank you so much as the lecturer in my uni didn't teach me as much information as you did. I'll definitely read the docs. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome; I hope you'll enjoy in Oracle!